# Can a process modify its own Page Table Entries in Linux?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, page-tables

It might make sense to not allow the same for security reasons as the address may be mapped to some address space which does not belong to the process. But can it modify to change the Page Table entry for an address it has access to?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but calls like `mprotect()` do make it possible.